# direct input for bash operation

Tags: bash, parsing

I am running the command

```
while IFS= read -r file;do split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file";done < file.list.txt
```

which accepts as input a text file (`file.list.txt`) holding a list of files of the form

```
job1
job2
```

I need a command which accepts a single input file. But If i write

```
while IFS= read -r file;do split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file";done < job1
```

I only get the file printed to standard out. How can I make that command accept a single file instead of a file list?

Answer (score 2):

The redirection operator accepts a file name to open and read input from.

```
command <file
```

To accept a single string, Bash 3.x has something called a "here string":

```
command <<<"string"
```

or you can use a pipe:

```
echo "string" | command
```

So for your question, try

```
echo "job1" |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file"
done
```

For completeness sake, maybe also mention here documents:

```
while read file; do
    split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file"
done <<'____HERE'
    job1
____HERE
```

which allows you to put a "pseudo-file" in the script itself between the `<<` and the terminating heredoc delimiter.

Comment: Nice overview, but unless you prefix `'____HERE'` with `-` and use only _tabs_ as the leading whitespace on the document lines,
the leading whitespace will become part of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
split -l 20000 -d job1 job1
```

should do the same as

```
while IFS= read -r file;do split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file";done < file.list.txt
```

with `file.list.txt` only consisting of the line

```
job1
```

Comment: I read that as a degenerate case, rather than the exclusive use case the user needs to support. But then, the OP isn't exceedingly clear about their larger-scale intent.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a *variable* to hold the input filename in this case:

```
file='job1'
split -l 20000 -d "$file" "$file"
```

You can save a few keystrokes with [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
file='job1'
split -l 20000 -d "$file"{,}
```

- `"$file"{,}` effectively *doubles* `$file`, effectively resulting in the same command as above.